# Выборка строк с максимальным значением в 2х полях

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица с множеством строк и полей, среди полей есть поля `sub_id`, `date` и `status`. Есть ли способ создать выборку тех строк, которые имеют максимальную `date` среди одинаковых `sub_id`, а если вдруг получается так, что максимальная `date` не одна, то уже выбрать те, у которых максимальный `status` среди тех у кого одинаковый `sub_id` и одинаковая максимальная `date`?
Сейчас я делаю так:

```
SELECT o.`id`,o.`sub_id`, o.`date`, o.`status`
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(`date`) `max_date`, `sub_id` FROM `orders` GROUP BY `sub_id`) o2 ON o2.`max_date`=o.`date` AND o2.`sub_id`=o.`sub_id`
FROM `orders` o
```

такое вроде работает, но вот если вдруг с одним и тем же `sub_id` есть более одной строки с одинаковой `date`, то выборка выбирает "первую попавшуюся", а хотелось бы выбрать ту, что с бОльшим `status`.

Возможно такое сделать?

Comment: *а если вдруг получается так, что максимальная date не одна, то* А если одна - всё равно должно делаться ровно то же самое, только с поправкой на тривиальность. Иными словами - выбирайте именно записи, у которых при максимальной `date` максимальный `status`.

Comment: ну да, только вот не пойму как так делать...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT o3.*
FROM orders AS o3,
(
    SELECT o2.sub_id, o2.date, MAX(status) AS status
    FROM orders AS o2,
    (
        SELECT o1.sub_id, MAX(o1.date) AS date
        FROM orders AS o1
        GROUP BY o1.sub_id
    ) AS sq1
    WHERE o2.sub_id = sq1.sub_id AND o2.date = sq1.date
    GROUP BY o2.sub_id, o2.date
) AS sq2
WHERE o3.sub_id = sq2.sub_id AND o3.date = sq2.date AND o3.status = sq2.status
```

> как сюда прислюнить LEFT JOIN полей из другой таблицы связанных с этой по sub_id?

```
SELECT o3.*, sometable.somefield
FROM orders AS o3
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT o2.sub_id, o2.date, MAX(status) AS status
    FROM orders AS o2,
    (
        SELECT o1.sub_id, MAX(o1.date) AS date
        FROM orders AS o1
        GROUP BY o1.sub_id
    ) AS sq1 
    WHERE o2.sub_id = sq1.sub_id AND o2.date = sq1.date
    GROUP BY o2.sub_id, o2.date
) AS sq2 ON o3.sub_id = sq2.sub_id AND o3.date = sq2.date AND o3.status = sq2.status
LEFT JOIN sometable ON sometable.sub_id = o3.sub_id
```

Comment: спасибо, вот только как сюда прислюнить `LEFT JOIN` полей из другой таблицы связанных с этой по `sub_id`? Ставлю сразу перед `WHERE`, но ругается на неожиданность значения.