# Выборка уникальных строк по одному полю

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Имеется таблица **kubki**, в ней есть поле **seria**, нужно выбрать все уникальные значения строк в поле **seria**, и при этом выбрать все остальные столбцы.

То есть, как

```
select DISTINCT(seria) from kubki;
```

Но еще с добавлением других столбцов, например **id**

Не могу понять, как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Уже и подзапрос пробовал, и join, но не выходит

Comment: А что значит "выбрать все остальные столбцы" ? если у вас есть две записи с seria=1, а в другом поле у одной записи значение 1, а у второй 2, то какое из значений должно быть показано в той единственной записи, которая будет выбрана ? прочитайте так же про group by https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599802/194569

Comment: А нельзя отсортировать предварительно, и потом уже отфильтровать?

Comment: @mike, group by тоже пробовал, не вышло совладать

Comment: @Mike, я, конечно, могу выбрать все серии уникальные, а потом в цикле под каждую серию выбирать limit 1, с order by по price, к примеру, но это будет слишком...

Comment: Ага, т.е. вам нужна запись, например с минимальным price ?

Comment: @Mike, да. Чтобы понятнее было, в таблице есть разные товары (кубки), они есть из одной серии, но нужно выбрать на страницу по одному из серии, с минимальной ценой, например

Comment: Тут прямо в вопросе то что вам надо https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722315/194569  так же есть другие (более замороченные, но иногда более быстрые) подходы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/496532/194569

Comment: @mike
    SELECT k3.* FROM kubki AS k3, ( SELECT k2.id, MAX(k2.price) AS price FROM kubki AS k2, ( SELECT k1.id, MAX(k1.price) AS price FROM kubki AS k1 GROUP BY k1.id ) AS sq1 WHERE k2.id = sq1.id AND k2.price = sq1.price GROUP BY k2.id, k2.price ) AS sq2 WHERE k3.id = sq2.id AND k3.price = sq2.price 

Просто скопировал, чтобы проверить, так что, вероятнее, внутренний, который k1 не нужен, но все равно выбраны все строки :(

Comment: @Mike https://pastebin.com/pKHGBCeS

Comment: @mike, получилось!)

Comment: а так не проще - `SELECT k3.* FROM kubki AS k3  where (k3.seria, k3.price) in (SELECT k2.seria, MIN(k2.price)  FROM kubki AS k2 group by k2.seria)`

Comment: Ок, только сложновато, вам второй уровень не нужен https://pastebin.com/AtLVBSCv  Но если будут две записи с одинаковым seria и price и этот прайс будет как раз нужным, возникнут проблемы, вы получите все записи с таким price. Если такие ситуации возможны, то может стоит добавить еще какое нибудь поле

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, проще

Comment: @mike ещё раз спасибо за наводку

Comment: @mike а почему в другой таблице, имеющей схожую структуру, (тоже есть seria), не работает запрос как нужно, выбирает все абсолютно строки?

Comment: @Vorozhbit Может у вас там seria уникальна ? или price одинаковые

Comment: @Mike, да, точно, цена одна

Comment: @Mike а как добавить в запрос поле еще одно, например, еще есть высота - height

Comment: А это было написано в ответе по самой первой ссылке, что я давал. а так думаю для облегчения жизни можно собирать несколько полей в один текст и брать max() от него. ну и сравнивать конечно точно так же собранную строку. только для полей надо обязательно использовать lpad, что бы они занимали строго определенную длину в строке, для того что бы max когда будет значения сранивать на больше-меньше делала это корректно. что то вроде `concat(lpad(price,10,'0'), lpad(height, 10, '0'))` длину дополнения выбрать по максимальной длине значений в БД в текстовом виде

Comment: @mike, премного благодарен !